# Stamps and weight

Tags: combinatorics

Here is my problem:

> Ryan's letter weighs $\dfrac 9{10}\,\mathrm{oz}$. Stamps weigh $\dfrac 1{30}\,\mathrm{oz}$ each. The cost of mailing the first ounce, or fraction thereof costs $37$ cents and each additional ounce, or fraction thereof costs $23$ cents. If Ryan only has $1$ cent stamps, how many stamps should he use? Remember he is paying for the weight of the stamps, too. Assume there are no physical constraints regarding the number of stamps or the size of the envelope.

Is there any way to do it better than brute force

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's set up the equation

$${\color{green}{37\times\left(\dfrac 9{10} + \dfrac1{30}y\right)}} + {\color{blue}{23\times\dfrac1{30}\times\left(x - y\right)}} = {\color{red}{1\times x}}$$

Here is the breakdown of the equation:

Let $x$ be the total number of stamps that Ryan needs to use. Since each stamp is worth $1$ cent, the total cost of the stamps is $1\times x = x$ cents. The right-hand side of the equation (in ${\color{red}{\text{red}}}$), therefore, represents the total cost that Ryan would have to pay.

The first ounce costs $37$ cents. Since the letter weighs $\dfrac 9{10}\,\mathrm{oz}$, some of the stamps will contribute to the remaining $\dfrac 1{10}\,\mathrm{oz}$ for the first ounce. We denote this number of stamps by $y$. The first part of the equation on the left-hand side (in ${\color{green}{\text{green}}}$) represents the cost of the first ounce. Calculation of $y$ is trivial (there is already a hint in this paragraph) and I will leave this for you.

Additional stamps contribute to the remaining weight, i.e., in addition to the first ounce. Since the total number of stamps is $x$, and $y$ of these contribute to the first ounce, $x - y$ stamps contribute to the additional weight. The second part of the equation on the left-hand side (in ${\color{blue}{\text{blue}}}$) represents the cost of the additional weight.

Solving for $x$, i.e., the total number of stamps Ryan has to use, is now straightforward. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes thank you! I got 152 as the answer :)